# JAWS 2022 does not read chrome web page upon launch

Tags: google-chrome, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I am using JAWS 2022 to check accessibility of web pages on chrome. Once I launch the JAWS 2022 software , I am able to read webpages on IE but for some reason JAWS is not reading out chrome web page content even when I focus on specific readable elements ( although page title is read out at first when focus goes inside chrome window ). The only work around I could find was to restore JAWS to factory settings multiple times and then magically it starts reading chrome web page without any issues. But this method is extremely unreliable and causes a lot of trouble each time I open JAWS just to get it to read chrome web page. Any idea why this may be happening / how to fix this?

Comment: I have never had that kind of problem.  I use JAWS, NVDA, VoiceOver, and Talkback quite a bit, across various browsers.  Do you have a production URL I can try?  Is it only JAWS/Chrome that doesn't work?  You mentioned JAWS/IE was ok.  What about JAWS/Edge or JAWS/Firefox?  What about NVDA?  Does NVDA work with IE, Chrome, Edge, FF?

Comment: Is this happening for a specific web page or for any page in Chrome?